# Best rails way to implement custom validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

I am looking for the best way to implement custom validations. I am aware of this :

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => {:scope => :user_id}
```

It works perfect. But, I want to do something like this (fictive case but it illustrates well) :

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => {:scope => 'user.name'}
```

I am thinking of using customs validations like explained [here on rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3) but it seems a little overkill to use a module for this.

Anyone ?

Comment: just a curiosity, but what are you trying to validate with this? what's the difference between your approach and validates :email, :uniqueness => true??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a validation method.

```
class Model

  validate :validate_email_with_scope

  private

    def validate_email_with_scope
      if Model.where(...).any?
        errors.add(:email, 'is not unique')
      end
    end

end
```

Replace `Model.where(...).any?` with your query.

Comment: Works great. How can you tell active record to exclude the current object id from the where request ?

Comment: `where('foo = ? AND id <> ?', 'bar', id)`